# Does GRUB install itself on every disk?

Tags: grub2

I have 4 hard disks. One of them houses Debian, one Windows and others are just storage. Does GRUB install itself on every MBR of every hard disk? (I have not specified any path explicitly for GRUB installation, left it to Debian installer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It normally installs only—and only needs to install itself—on the drive from which the machine is booted.

I only use installation on a different drive if I intend to take an (old) boot drive out of the machine, when I have to change the boot order and at one time when I had a RAID-1 mirrored root filesystem (so the boot drive could die and I could reboot the other drive of the downgraded array—not sure it would have worked, never had to use it).